# AsyncStoragePackage is defined multiple times

Tags: reactjs, react-native

What went wrong:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:multiDexListDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Error while merging dex archives:
     Type com.reactnativecommunity.asyncstorage.AsyncStoragePackage is defined multiple times: C:\Users\JesusGuillermoCiscom\Documents\a\exitusforce\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dynatraceTransformer\debug\101.jar:com/reactnativecommunity/asyncstorage/AsyncStoragePackage.class, C:\Users\JesusGuillermoCiscom\Documents\a\exitusforce\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dynatraceTransformer\debug\106.jar:com/reactnativecommunity/asyncstorage/AsyncStoragePackage.class
     Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
```

This happened after I installed [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dynatrace/react-native-plugin?activeTab=readme#using-a-second-transformer-besides-the-dynatrace-transformer).

It seems  that dynatrace duplicates the async storage dependency and I don't know how to fix this.

I already deleted the node_module, cd/android gradlewclean and tried to rebuild the project.

Comment: have you manage to solve it?

Comment: yes, when they uploaded a new version of the package it fixed my problem

Answer (score 3):

The issue in my case was a definition of 2 packages in my package.json:

- [@react-native-community/async-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/async-storage) (Deprecated)
- [react-native-async-storage/async-storage](https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage)

Once I remove the deprecated one issue resolved.
Note that if you are using Yarn Workspaces that you might have the deprecated package in one of your workspaces.